# Change fill of element inside SVG

Tags: css

My page:
https://galina.xyz/makiyazh/oshibki-pri-makiyazhe/

Quotation marks icon is organized like this:

```
.n-quotation-dumbbells:before {
    background-image: url("https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/quotation-dumbbells.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content:"";
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;     
}
```

[image]

The icon is an SVG. In the SVG I've organized a class "quotation-mark".

[image]

Full SVG text is here: https://dpaste.org/FQpp

Could you help me understand how to change the color of the quotation marks depending on the class.

Now my CSS looks like this:

```
.n-quotation-dumbbells:before {
    background-image: url("https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/quotation-dumbbells.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content:"";
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;     
}
```

But I want to use just one background SVG image, but change the dummbells colour:

```
<span class="n-quotation-dumbbells lemon-fill">
```

So, in this case I want the colour to be lemon.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is changing the colour inside SVG easy in this case?
3. What is the easiest way (maybe changing the image itself is easier)?

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text to your question, not as an image.

Comment: But I did it. As a pastebin insertion.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,

But to my knowledge, you'll have to either **write each color** you wanna add or make a loop with **scss**

I'll do an example for the write each color solution.

```css
/* Here's the css solution */

span[color="orange"] *:not(defs) {
  fill: orange!important;
}
span[color="red"] *:not(defs) {
  fill: red!important;
}

/* Here's the scss solution */
$colors: [
  "green" : "#00ff00",
  "blue": "#0000ff"
]
$each $color, $value in $colors {
  span[color="#{$color}"] *:not(defs){
    fill: $value;
  }
}
```

```html
<span color="orange">
  <svg
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
     width="210mm"
     height="210mm"
     viewBox="0 0 210 210"
     version="1.1"
     id="svg207"
     inkscape:version="0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)"
     sodipodi:docname="lemon_left.svg">
    <defs
       id="defs201" />
    <sodipodi:namedview
       id="base"
       pagecolor="#ffffff"
       bordercolor="#666666"
       borderopacity="1.0"
       inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
       inkscape:pageshadow="2"
       inkscape:zoom="0.49497475"
       inkscape:cx="40.01939"
       inkscape:cy="181.32413"
       inkscape:document-units="mm"
       inkscape:current-layer="g104"
       showgrid="false"
       inkscape:window-width="1208"
       inkscape:window-height="960"
       inkscape:window-x="72"
       inkscape:window-y="27"
       inkscape:window-maximized="1"
       showguides="true"
       inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
       inkscape:lockguides="false" />
    <metadata
       id="metadata204">
      <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work
           rdf:about="">
          <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
          <dc:type
             rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
          <dc:title />
        </cc:Work>
      </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g
       inkscape:label="Layer 1"
       inkscape:groupmode="layer"
       id="layer1"
       transform="translate(0,-87)">
      <g
         transform="matrix(0.28616797,0,0,0.28746471,-55.949769,590.11604)"
         id="g104">
        <path
           style="stroke-width:0.06735482"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
           d="m 829.16053,-1409.9985 c -28.95054,-3.126 -58.51987,8.2929 -78.36909,30.4215 -7.31878,7.9638 -9.75437,11.8643 -15.25099,24.6265 -4.01515,9.2852 -6.9312,18.1976 -7.7077,23.5742 l -1.29902,8.4173 -103.02298,46.4123 c -71.13544,31.851 -103.67906,45.6595 -104.83974,44.5437 -0.94118,-0.8668 -6.70494,-4.4677 -12.85165,-7.9071 -45.81475,-25.4764 -104.34116,-4.6772 -126.15869,45.1217 -11.37,25.6884 -11.52847,49.8449 -0.67201,75.4794 11.02652,26.0319 25.07633,39.9445 50.68097,50.1861 18.44575,7.378 30.72363,8.8782 48.31951,5.9986 40.33825,-6.7822 72.40277,-41.4229 76.87427,-82.7161 0.17084,-2.5301 20.72726,-12.3574 103.40296,-49.5102 l 103.0913,-46.2166 6.56859,4.4134 c 9.32475,6.3281 27.74059,13.3722 38.2101,14.632 43.0667,5.2005 82.41609,-18.5629 97.88979,-59.1883 5.6949,-14.952 7.4573,-27.9049 6.1289,-42.7383 -2.2805,-23.9975 -12.3882,-44.9408 -29.5899,-61.417 -8.044,-7.6092 -10.7233,-9.3322 -25.97842,-15.9173 -12.14731,-5.1807 -19.52151,-7.4789 -25.4262,-8.2158 z m 29.01976,48.3434 c 8.93016,7.7953 16.77686,21.342 15.86816,27.4781 -1.668,11.0365 -16.00655,12.4523 -21.57708,2.0996 -4.6228,-8.6779 -7.10624,-10.4837 -21.42402,-16.2107 -14.31777,-5.7269 -17.33829,-6.1227 -26.28586,-3.0336 -7.27729,2.4543 -13.97388,-0.3853 -15.86003,-6.6659 -2.25859,-7.403 0.15571,-11.6414 8.60485,-15.0908 19.62535,-8.2454 43.17796,-3.8677 60.67398,11.4233 z"
           id="path1817" />
        <g
           transform="matrix(-16.657112,0,0,17.0697,-3241.3463,-8173.5724)"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccsc"
           id="path1873_1_-0-2">
          <path
             id="path39-9-2"
             d="m -213.5,386.6 c 5.1,5.7 1.6,15.7 -2.7,19.5 -3.6,3.3 -9.6,6 -10.2,5 -0.9,-1.5 2.6,-2.5 5.3,-4.9 3.3,-3.6 4.4,-5.2 -0.2,-7.2 -4.9,-2.2 -5,-4.4 -5.2,-7.2 -0.3,-6.9 8,-10.2 13,-5.2 z"
             class="quotation-mark"
             inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
             style="fill:#FF0000" />
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(-16.657112,0,0,17.0697,-3241.3463,-8173.5724)"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccsc"
           id="path1875_1_-9-77">
          <path
             id="path42-2-6"
             d="m -232.7,386.5 c 5.1,5.7 1.6,15.7 -2.7,19.5 -3.6,3.3 -9.6,6 -10.2,5 -0.9,-1.5 2.6,-2.5 5.3,-4.9 3.3,-3.6 4.4,-5.2 -0.2,-7.2 -4.9,-2.2 -5,-4.4 -5.2,-7.2 -0.2,-6.9 8,-10.2 13,-5.2 z"
             class="quotation-mark"
             inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
             style="fill:#FF0000" />
        </g>
        <path
           style="stroke-width:0.06735482"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
           d="m 811.96443,-1647.321 c -28.82304,-19.0681 -63.9884,-20.9012 -94.12136,-4.9784 -10.33066,5.4366 -26.91299,20.2817 -32.15893,28.5723 l -3.55231,5.9168 -112.4794,-6.2034 c -100.57963,-5.5422 -112.56161,-6.5217 -114.18576,-9.5082 -4.85685,-9.1664 -21.52791,-28.4286 -29.90035,-34.3511 -21.99526,-15.5821 -51.1368,-20.5112 -76.86006,-12.9251 -16.79954,5.0751 -24.77649,9.5649 -37.0892,20.8939 -28.37938,26.3134 -37.89399,66.0036 -24.59474,103.6254 4.01726,11.1576 4.88849,12.6011 18.01505,27.583 16.4871,18.8175 24.98404,24.4331 45.0096,29.6125 20.64398,5.4261 40.92461,3.8649 59.68062,-4.6415 8.68203,-3.9197 12.59274,-6.7024 23.58853,-16.8196 7.25791,-6.6781 14.55588,-14.2084 16.24952,-16.5823 l 3.05556,-4.4426 112.15436,6.2917 112.2633,6.1913 2.62542,5.7216 c 3.67,7.8117 19.87039,26.0776 28.24234,32.0097 13.11383,9.3031 31.09516,15.548 47.58512,16.4574 68.55871,3.6748 116.76727,-67.5492 89.40695,-132.3234 -5.84541,-13.9383 -20.79613,-32.135 -32.93426,-40.1 z m 3.04795,53.5691 c 4.78465,10.4517 6.48481,25.9864 3.82821,32.7008 -1.56529,3.8778 -2.33762,4.5884 -5.93604,5.4619 -2.33094,0.5136 -6.08934,0.3063 -8.44588,-0.5768 -3.90897,-1.2875 -4.50018,-1.9623 -5.70756,-6.9634 -0.67898,-3.0406 -1.5502,-8.3419 -1.99528,-11.7994 -0.52839,-5.8182 -1.49741,-7.3733 -10.67666,-17.85 l -10.17053,-11.608 -9.62829,-1.9265 c -11.18074,-2.3306 -14.3813,-5.0855 -13.8906,-12.4553 0.31787,-8.0265 5.42546,-11.7088 14.7014,-10.8785 20.50909,1.8939 39.03598,15.7831 47.92123,35.8952 z"
           id="path1815" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</span>
<span color="red">
  <svg
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
     width="210mm"
     height="210mm"
     viewBox="0 0 210 210"
     version="1.1"
     id="svg207"
     inkscape:version="0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)"
     sodipodi:docname="lemon_left.svg">
    <defs
       id="defs201" />
    <sodipodi:namedview
       id="base"
       pagecolor="#ffffff"
       bordercolor="#666666"
       borderopacity="1.0"
       inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
       inkscape:pageshadow="2"
       inkscape:zoom="0.49497475"
       inkscape:cx="40.01939"
       inkscape:cy="181.32413"
       inkscape:document-units="mm"
       inkscape:current-layer="g104"
       showgrid="false"
       inkscape:window-width="1208"
       inkscape:window-height="960"
       inkscape:window-x="72"
       inkscape:window-y="27"
       inkscape:window-maximized="1"
       showguides="true"
       inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
       inkscape:lockguides="false" />
    <metadata
       id="metadata204">
      <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work
           rdf:about="">
          <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
          <dc:type
             rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
          <dc:title />
        </cc:Work>
      </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g
       inkscape:label="Layer 1"
       inkscape:groupmode="layer"
       id="layer1"
       transform="translate(0,-87)">
      <g
         transform="matrix(0.28616797,0,0,0.28746471,-55.949769,590.11604)"
         id="g104">
        <path
           style="stroke-width:0.06735482"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
           d="m 829.16053,-1409.9985 c -28.95054,-3.126 -58.51987,8.2929 -78.36909,30.4215 -7.31878,7.9638 -9.75437,11.8643 -15.25099,24.6265 -4.01515,9.2852 -6.9312,18.1976 -7.7077,23.5742 l -1.29902,8.4173 -103.02298,46.4123 c -71.13544,31.851 -103.67906,45.6595 -104.83974,44.5437 -0.94118,-0.8668 -6.70494,-4.4677 -12.85165,-7.9071 -45.81475,-25.4764 -104.34116,-4.6772 -126.15869,45.1217 -11.37,25.6884 -11.52847,49.8449 -0.67201,75.4794 11.02652,26.0319 25.07633,39.9445 50.68097,50.1861 18.44575,7.378 30.72363,8.8782 48.31951,5.9986 40.33825,-6.7822 72.40277,-41.4229 76.87427,-82.7161 0.17084,-2.5301 20.72726,-12.3574 103.40296,-49.5102 l 103.0913,-46.2166 6.56859,4.4134 c 9.32475,6.3281 27.74059,13.3722 38.2101,14.632 43.0667,5.2005 82.41609,-18.5629 97.88979,-59.1883 5.6949,-14.952 7.4573,-27.9049 6.1289,-42.7383 -2.2805,-23.9975 -12.3882,-44.9408 -29.5899,-61.417 -8.044,-7.6092 -10.7233,-9.3322 -25.97842,-15.9173 -12.14731,-5.1807 -19.52151,-7.4789 -25.4262,-8.2158 z m 29.01976,48.3434 c 8.93016,7.7953 16.77686,21.342 15.86816,27.4781 -1.668,11.0365 -16.00655,12.4523 -21.57708,2.0996 -4.6228,-8.6779 -7.10624,-10.4837 -21.42402,-16.2107 -14.31777,-5.7269 -17.33829,-6.1227 -26.28586,-3.0336 -7.27729,2.4543 -13.97388,-0.3853 -15.86003,-6.6659 -2.25859,-7.403 0.15571,-11.6414 8.60485,-15.0908 19.62535,-8.2454 43.17796,-3.8677 60.67398,11.4233 z"
           id="path1817" />
        <g
           transform="matrix(-16.657112,0,0,17.0697,-3241.3463,-8173.5724)"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccsc"
           id="path1873_1_-0-2">
          <path
             id="path39-9-2"
             d="m -213.5,386.6 c 5.1,5.7 1.6,15.7 -2.7,19.5 -3.6,3.3 -9.6,6 -10.2,5 -0.9,-1.5 2.6,-2.5 5.3,-4.9 3.3,-3.6 4.4,-5.2 -0.2,-7.2 -4.9,-2.2 -5,-4.4 -5.2,-7.2 -0.3,-6.9 8,-10.2 13,-5.2 z"
             class="quotation-mark"
             inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
             style="fill:#FF0000" />
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(-16.657112,0,0,17.0697,-3241.3463,-8173.5724)"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccsc"
           id="path1875_1_-9-77">
          <path
             id="path42-2-6"
             d="m -232.7,386.5 c 5.1,5.7 1.6,15.7 -2.7,19.5 -3.6,3.3 -9.6,6 -10.2,5 -0.9,-1.5 2.6,-2.5 5.3,-4.9 3.3,-3.6 4.4,-5.2 -0.2,-7.2 -4.9,-2.2 -5,-4.4 -5.2,-7.2 -0.2,-6.9 8,-10.2 13,-5.2 z"
             class="quotation-mark"
             inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
             style="fill:#FF0000" />
        </g>
        <path
           style="stroke-width:0.06735482"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
           d="m 811.96443,-1647.321 c -28.82304,-19.0681 -63.9884,-20.9012 -94.12136,-4.9784 -10.33066,5.4366 -26.91299,20.2817 -32.15893,28.5723 l -3.55231,5.9168 -112.4794,-6.2034 c -100.57963,-5.5422 -112.56161,-6.5217 -114.18576,-9.5082 -4.85685,-9.1664 -21.52791,-28.4286 -29.90035,-34.3511 -21.99526,-15.5821 -51.1368,-20.5112 -76.86006,-12.9251 -16.79954,5.0751 -24.77649,9.5649 -37.0892,20.8939 -28.37938,26.3134 -37.89399,66.0036 -24.59474,103.6254 4.01726,11.1576 4.88849,12.6011 18.01505,27.583 16.4871,18.8175 24.98404,24.4331 45.0096,29.6125 20.64398,5.4261 40.92461,3.8649 59.68062,-4.6415 8.68203,-3.9197 12.59274,-6.7024 23.58853,-16.8196 7.25791,-6.6781 14.55588,-14.2084 16.24952,-16.5823 l 3.05556,-4.4426 112.15436,6.2917 112.2633,6.1913 2.62542,5.7216 c 3.67,7.8117 19.87039,26.0776 28.24234,32.0097 13.11383,9.3031 31.09516,15.548 47.58512,16.4574 68.55871,3.6748 116.76727,-67.5492 89.40695,-132.3234 -5.84541,-13.9383 -20.79613,-32.135 -32.93426,-40.1 z m 3.04795,53.5691 c 4.78465,10.4517 6.48481,25.9864 3.82821,32.7008 -1.56529,3.8778 -2.33762,4.5884 -5.93604,5.4619 -2.33094,0.5136 -6.08934,0.3063 -8.44588,-0.5768 -3.90897,-1.2875 -4.50018,-1.9623 -5.70756,-6.9634 -0.67898,-3.0406 -1.5502,-8.3419 -1.99528,-11.7994 -0.52839,-5.8182 -1.49741,-7.3733 -10.67666,-17.85 l -10.17053,-11.608 -9.62829,-1.9265 c -11.18074,-2.3306 -14.3813,-5.0855 -13.8906,-12.4553 0.31787,-8.0265 5.42546,-11.7088 14.7014,-10.8785 20.50909,1.8939 39.03598,15.7831 47.92123,35.8952 z"
           id="path1815" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</span>
```

In my case, I apply the style to the **whole svg**, but you can **target it more precisely** if you want.

Answer (score -1):

I can help you with your question.

1. If you are able to modify the SVG file itself please remove inline-style `style="fill:#FF0000"` which makes it red.
2. Add respective CSS styles:

```css
.quotation-mark {
    fill: pink;
}
```

Comment: I have done that. Please visit the page again. But the quotation marks are now blck. And have I understood you correctly that there is no difference whether this is a CSS class or a class inside SVG?

Comment: @Michael,  yes It renders as HTML element `path` which you can apply `fill` style

Comment: @Michael , as I can see [here](https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/quotation-dumbbells.svg) `style="fill:#FF0000"` still on SVG Path element. Can you remove it?

Comment: To the best of my ability I can't find any fill there. I have removed it.

Comment: @Michael, hope [this](https://ibb.co/dL1jsyf) helps

Comment: Strange: https://c.radikal.ru/c10/2110/57/d0c588072924.png